# How can I do $and queries against an array in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, intersection

I have a collection in mongo where objects appear as follows:

```
{ name:"Scott", bio:"Stumped", roles:["USR","ADM"] }
```

Many more roles are possible. I want to perform any combination of intersection queries, like so:

```
db.coll.find({$and:[{roles:"USR"},{roles:{$ne:"ADM"}}]})
```

Some queries may be all role =, some may be all roles !=, and some may be mixed as with the above example. I have had some measure of success with $or and $nor, but absolutely no query I can fathom works with $and. I have even tried leveraging $where and $elemMatch to emulate what I want. I am also really trying to avoid multiple queries w/ the application handling intersection. Ideas?

Comment: Hint?: I know in mongo collections are just stored as ordered strings internal to mongo.. maybe there is some query where you can list out the serialized permutations you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.coll.find("roles":{$all:["USR","ADM"]}})
```

I think this would help you, at least it returns the result you are looking for

Comment: Take a second look, I want some of the criteria to be negated. Example: Give me all objects where roles contains USR but not ADM. This does solve part of my question though, getting closer!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer:

```
db.coll.find( {roles : { $all : ["USR"], $nin : ["ADM"]}} )
```

Thanks Hohhi for leading me down the right path!